# What keystrokes brings up the prompt to issue Lisp commands?

Tags: key-bindings, commands

I am editing a file and I want to set the tab width (more likely the indent width) to 2 and I have come across a command `(setq tab-width 2)` but when I use `M-x` (i.e. `Alt-x`) on my system and I enter `(setq tab-width 2)` I get the message [No match].

I think the keystroke `M-x` is the wrong one. I get list of commands to select from, but what I am looking for is the right place to change a setting in Emacs with a Lisp command.

Comment: FYI, you can also use the `set-variable` interactive command: `M-x set-variable tab-width ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `eval-expression`, bound by default to `M-:`.

`M-:` is different from `M-x`, which is bound to `execute-extended-command`.  The latter is used specifically for *commands* (interactive functions that do something).  The former is used to evaluate a lisp expression, which is what you're trying to do when you're setting the value of some variable.

You can read more about it in the manual nodes on:

- [Evaluating Emacs Lisp Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html), and
- [What does `M-x command` mean?](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Extended-commands.html)